# How to reduce the curvature of the map line in AmCharts 5

Tags: amcharts, amcharts5

In Amchart 5 maps, I'm using am5map.MapLineSeries to create a bunch of lines and have set lineType to curve. This basically means the line will be curved and also this line can cross -180/180 longitude.

1. How do we reduce the curvature of the curved line?
2. How to disable the -180/180 longitude crossing of the line while keeping the line curved? like in the lineType:'straight'

---

[image: Image for reference]

[am5 demo- Map with Curved Lines](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/map-with-curved-lines/)

In the above link, change the origin coordinates to somewhere in south Asia and one of the destination coordinates to lets say somewhere in North/South America, you will see the curved line to go beyond -180/180 longitude (as it's taking the shortest distance).